# Using incremental integer in Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, normalization, recurrent-neural-network, brain.js

I am using Brain.js to develop a neural network for a project of mine. The idea is to have something like this:

```
{ input: [day, month, hour, minute], output: some categoryID }
```

Basically, I will train the network to learn user's habits over time, so that later the network can predict a user's favourite category when given a time.

My main problem is that these "categories" is not a fixed array. I will most likely, over time, add, change or remove categories from the project. Each category has it own `categoryID`, which is auto-incremental.

**How can I - in the best way - output a categoryID in a neural network?**

Please keep in mind that the project may have thousands of categories in the future. The network must be able to handle that.

Thanks for your help!